# How to close an excel file after reading it through pandas dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, google-chrome

I am trying to read an excel file and then insert the data into Sql server database. Currently my connection to DB is not working. But after I run the python code, it doesnot allow me to edit the excel sheet again. It doesnot even allow me to delete the file from my local.

I am using the below code:

```
f = request.files['file'] #I am uploading the file from UI

df = pd.read_excel(f, engine='openpyxl') #input file is .xlsx hence used openpyxl)

print(df.to_string())
```

I tried using f.close() assuming it will close the opened excel. I am not saving the file anywhere on the server. The error I am getting while editing the excel after one time upload is "The action can't be completed because the file is open in Google Chrome"

Can use of context_manager work here. If yes how to ue it in this code. Please suggest.

Comment: I found that after closing chrome browser and killing the still running chrome processes helped in editing the excel file.